# What's the name of this nice spring contact?

Tags: connector, components, identification, pins

Ah, it is really a beauty isn't it (see picture below)? Around the package you see some spring contacts, really, really nice. I have some ESP8266MOD modules and like to use these spring contacts before soldering anything on the pins.

---

### [image: ic package with springs]

What is/are the name of this/these contact(s)?

---

**Update 04/12/2018:**

@bitsmack came up with the idea that these springs could be test-loops and search on it and found this picture:

[image: test-loops]

He could be right!

Comment: Now _that's_ nice :)  I've never seen those, but it looks like a great way to connect to the castellated vias!

Comment: Hmm, there's one for the ground connection. Makes me think they're standard test loops used in a very clever way.

Comment: Yeah, it is so clever it's so simple. Very nice.

Comment: @bitsmack, see my edited answer.

Comment: I wonder how much inductance those add in a high-speed net, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell well enough from the image, but is there any chance they're these with a leg cut off? Are they about 2.7 mm dia.?

[image: point]

They're from [Toby Electronics](https://www.toby.co.uk/pcb-hardware/test-points-and-pins/test-3-valcon-wire-form-test-point-27mm-diameter/).

Comment: Really awesome! I don't know the exact measurements because the photo and device showed is not mine. Your answer could be the answer. Great! haha, love it!

Comment: @Codebeat For a sense of scale, an we assume that the pitch on the rows of turned pin sockets is 0.1"?